# How I know what are the initial values of parameters of the "start" argument in fitdist function of fitdistrplus package?

Tags: distribution, data-fitting, chi-squared, model-fitting

I'm learning how a fit distributions to my data,I'm using the fitdist function of the fitdistrplus package, but for chi-squared distribution I need to give a named list with the initial values of parameter...

```
`surface.na.omit<-na.omit(cycle.data.frame$surf.time)`

`surface.na.omit`
```

> [1] 0.6666667 1.3666667 1.2833333 1.3666667 1.5833333 1.5333333
>   0.6666667 [8] 3.5333333 1.4166667 2.4500000 0.3333333 0.7666667 1.6000000 0.3833333 [15] 0.2666667 >1.8000000 3.2166667 1.3166667 2.4333333 2.2833333 2.3166667 [22] 4.1000000 1.0500000 0.3500000 >1.3166667 2.8333333 0.3166667 1.8333333 [29] 1.4666667 1.9833333 3.3666667 1.7000000 2.0666667 >1.4333333 0.5666667

```
`parameters.chis.surf<-fitdistr(surface.na.omit, "chi-squared")`
```

> Error en fitdistr(surface.na.omit, "chi-squared") : 
>   'start' must be a named list
>
> start is a named list giving the initial values of parameters of the
>   named distribution. This argument may be omitted for some
>   distributions for which reasonable starting values are computed >(see
>   details), and will not be taken into account if a closed formula is
>   used to estimate parameters.

but I don't have idea how to calculate or find this values...somebody can explain me this? :/  thank you so much...

Airy

Comment: Can you elaborate your question to be more specific? It is too general at this moment, checkout how other StackOverflow questions were asked. Welcome to SO.

Comment: yes, I have edited this morning...